# nltk tokenize measurement units

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to extract measurements from a messy dataset.
Some basic example entries would be:

- 1.5 gram of paracetamol
- 1.5g of paracetamol
- 1.5 grams. of paracetamol

I'm trying to extract the measurement and units for each entry so the result for all the above should be:
(1.5, g)

Some other questions proposed the use of NLTK for such a task but I'm running into trouble when doing the following:

```
import nltk

s1 = "1.5g of paracetamol"
s2 = "1.5  gram of paracetamol"

words_s1 = nltk.word_tokenize(s1)
words_s2 = nltk.word_tokenize(s2)

nltk.pos_tag(words_s1)
nltk.pos_tag(words_s2)
```

Which returns

```
[('1.5g', 'CD'), ('of', 'IN'), ('paracetamol', 'NN')]
[('1.5', 'CD'), ('gram', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('paracetamol', 'NN')]
```

The problem is that the unit 'g' is being kept as part of the CD in the first example. How could I get the following result?

```
[('1.5', 'CD'), ('g', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('paracetamol', 'NN')]
```

On the real data set the units are much more varied (mg, miligrams, kg, kgrams. ...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must tokenize the sentence yourself using `nltk.regexp_tokenize`, for example:

```
words_s1 = nltk.regexp_tokenize(s1, r'(?u)\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+')
```

Obviously, it needs to be improved to deal with more complicated cases.

Comment: This did actually work quite well, I just had to add support for commas as in some countries use a comma to denote the decimal values. Thanks!!